# javascript copy input file and get full file path

Tags: javascript, html, input

My first question is:
 - is it possible to copy from 1 file input data to another file input data?
what i mean is:

I have this input : `<input type="file" name="fileinput1" />`

Now I want to take what the user browse and copy the data to

`<input type="file" name="fileinput2" />`

Is that possible?

---

Second question, I have this element on my HTML input `multiple="multiple"`
it let me choose few files. Now I can see in the bottom that the names are getting together like this:

> "img1" "img2" "img3" "img4"

Is there any way to separate this into few inputs? Like to write inputs with JavaScript and with the path to everyone of them, is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is it possible to copy from 1 file input data to another file input data?

No. File inputs are read only.

> is there any way to separate this into few inputs?

No.

Comment: Not really read only. You can `input.value = null;` in most browsers (not in IE) to reset the field. But nothing else, yeah.